# Prove the convergence of a generalized harmonic series without using the integral test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

We already know that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n^\alpha}$ converges for $\alpha > 1$, so proving that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}$ converges should be trivial. Anyway, I am not allowed to use such result, and can't use the integral test, I should find some inequality for the comparison test or maybe apply the limit test.

Comment: What _are_ you allowed to use? And if only the comparison test, what relevant other series do you know the convergence of? You need something to be able to compare it to another series...

Comment: I know that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges. I am allowed to use also the root test, the ratio test, the Leibniz test, the direct and limit comparison test, the Cauchy condensation test, the absolute convergence test and the alternating series test.

Comment: Have you tried the Cauchy condensation test?

Comment: Cauchy condensation test will work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\alpha>1$, for any $n\geq 1$ we have
$$ \frac{1}{(n+1)^{\alpha}}\leq \frac{1}{\alpha-1}\left(\frac{1}{n^{\alpha-1}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{\alpha-1}}\right) \tag{1}$$
(this can be seen as a consequence of Bernoulli's inequality, for instance) hence it follows that $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$ is bounded by $1+\frac{1}{\alpha-1}$ for any $N\geq 1$ by creative telescoping.

As an alternative we may use Cauchy's condensation test: since $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2^n}{2^{\alpha n}}$ is convergent for any $\alpha>1$, the same applies to $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^\alpha}$.